# Help finding unknown distribution (for fun)

Tags: probability, distributions, skewness, range

I want to estimate the expected return of three different distributions.
So there is this game I play, which has a function where you invest in a marketing campaign. There are three different types: Type $1$, Type $2$, Type $3$. All three distributions are given "estimated" ranges, but values can occur outside of these ranges.

- Type $1$ is described as giving "safe" and "average" increase in demand.
  The "estimated range" is $30-50$.
- Type $2$ is described as more risky. It has a larger potential upside, but the probability of a low return is higher.
  The "estimated range" is  $27-75$.
- Type $3$ is described as very risky. It has the potential for a gigantic upside, but a large probability of a quite low effect.
  The "estimated range" is $6-250$.

I have experienced getting values outside of the ranges, so they are indeed only estimated payoffs. I don't quite understand what is meant (specifically) with "estimated range". My first thought was maybe $2$ standard deviations from the mean (~$96$%), but I don't really know.

I am curious if there is any way to quantify the differences in probabilities, and get the expected value from each type. The probabilities are hidden, and the skewness of the distribution is only described as lower or higher.

If I wanted to gain more details about this, how would I go about this?
My first thought was to gain a good sample for each type. From this we might be able to infer some more details about the distributions. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the lower value given for range 2 should actually be 20. If so these could be three lognormal distributions:
\begin{align}
LN(\mu,\sigma_1),&\ \ \mu=\ln\sqrt{1500}\simeq 3.66\\
LN(\mu,\sigma_2),&\ \ \sigma_2=\sigma_1 + \ln 1.5\\
LN(\mu,\sigma_3),&\ \ \sigma_3=\sigma_1 + \ln 5.0
\end{align}If
$$\sigma_1=\frac14\ln\frac53\simeq0.128$$
then the logs of the ranges would all be two standard deviations away from $\mu$, the mean of the corresponding normal distributions.